# Can I scrapping an HTML code snippet on browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-scraping, client-side

I have an HTML code block. How can I scrapping on browser this snippet with pure JS or JQuery?

Here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li>New York</li>
    <li>London</li>
    <li>Madrid</li>
    <li>Paris</li>
</ul>
```

The result I expected is:

```
<p>New York, London, Madrid, Paris</p>
```

I don't need to get a website's HTML document. I already have many blocks. I just want to client-side scrap these blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you already have a `string` containing the HTML so the only thing you need is to parse that string. This can be done using the `DOMParser` class. From then on it's straightforward because you get a `Document` returned which offers all the methods you should already now from the DOM of a webpage. In this case you can use `getElementsByTagName()` to get all the list items and then use `map()` to only get the `textContent` those list items.

```js
const domParser = new DOMParser();
const parsed = domParser.parseFromString(`
<ul>
  <li>New York</li>
  <li>London</li>
  <li>Madrid</li>
  <li>Paris</li>
</ul>`, "text/html");

const cityArray = [...parsed.getElementsByTagName("li")]
                    .map(li => li.textContent);
console.log(cityArray);
```

### Edit

Now that I am reading your edited question I think what you want to do has nothing to do with web scraping you just want to edit your existing DOM on the website you have.

In that case you can skip the whole parsing and instead do this:

```js
const cityArray = [...document.getElementsByTagName("li")]
  .map(li => li.textContent);
const pTag = document.createElement("p");
pTag.textContent = cityArray.join(", ");
document.body.appendChild(pTag);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>New York</li>
  <li>London</li>
  <li>Madrid</li>
  <li>Paris</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's great! I am getting html blocks from server side with php cURL. I thought if I scrape in the browser it will reduce the load on the server. But I'm still not sure if that's true. Do you think the server should do the scraping?

Comment: Actually you would web scrape some data  and put it in a file or database (only store the relevant data, not the HTML document!) and then the server would read that file or query that database whenever a client requests this information. In case of a single-page application you would send a HTTP request to some endpoint on the server and then render the data on the client side as desired. Or if you have a classic web application the server would just return some HTML it generates (e.g. with template engines) containing the data. Web scraping whenever a clients needs data is not very efficient.

Comment: Thanks again. I am making a live score application. I will get information from a site every minute. That's what I thought as I have a small server. But what you said makes a lot of sense.

Comment: In that case consider using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) which will allow you to push data from the server to your clients very efficiently.